# How to link Directory with multiple users with login

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an xamarin app. I was wanting to build in login system in the app. All users will be saved in directory; so when users will login the app will look if user exist in the users directory.

My problem is I don't know how to check this.

Here is my page called "**Constant.cs**"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LoginNavigation
{
    public class Constants
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> Credentials = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "user1", "pass" },
        { "user2", "pass" },
        { "user3", "pass" }
    };

    }


}
```

Here is **LoginPage.cs**

```
async void OnLoginButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var user = new User {
        Username = usernameEntry.Text,
        Password = passwordEntry.Text
    };

    var isValid = AreCredentialsCorrect (user);
    if (isValid) {
        App.IsUserLoggedIn = true;
        //Navigation.InsertPageBefore (new MainPageCS (), this);
        Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new MainPageCS(), Navigation.NavigationStack.First());
        await Navigation.PopAsync ();
    } else {
        messageLabel.Text = "Login failed";
        passwordEntry.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}

bool AreCredentialsCorrect(User user)
{
    return (Credentials.ContainsKey(user) && Credentials[user] == Password);

}
```

I am not sure how I can get the login right so app get the username and password from the login form; than it match if exist. if does than it logins and if not it throw error.

Many Thanks in advance.

**Error Image**
[Error on LoginPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mac4V.png)

Comment: please do NOT post the same question multiple times.  If you have questions about the answer I provided on the original question, use comments and edits to respond.

Comment: and it would be great if you could accept an answer that helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. 
But Credidentials is part of the class Constants, so you have to either create an instance of that class, like this:

```
bool AreCredentialsCorrect(User user)
{
  var constants= new Constants();
  return (constants.Credentials.ContainsKey(user.Username) && Credentials[user.Username] == user.Password);
}
```

or you make constants a static class, like this:

```
public static class Constants
{
  public static Dictionary<string, string> Credentials = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
```

and you use it like this:

```
bool AreCredentialsCorrect(User user)
{
  return (Constants.Credentials.ContainsKey(user.Username) && Credentials[user.Username] == user.Password);
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: I get the error.  'object' does not contain a definition for 'ContainsKey' and no extension method 'ContainsKey' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Hi @Jeremy; I tried the above code still does not work. I have added the image of error on in my original question.

Comment: Yes, the dictionary has to be public, of course. And it takes a string, so you have to use user.Username instead of just user. See my edited answer.